# replace strings in column with matching value from another file using awk

Tags: awk, replace

I'm having a little issue trying to use awk to replace some strings in a column using another file as a reference for the replacement.
I want the strings in the third column of my File2 to be replaced by the strings in the second column of File1 when they match the string of the first column of File1.

Here are the files and the desired outcome to be more clear.

File1

```
AAA   XZA
AAB   XSZ
AAC   XWQ
BAA   XCD
```

File2

```
ADZ-4       128720       AAA   451351351   5135   jhgt   215
SZQ-2       036051       AAB   55654   grt
KFD-9       036266       AAC 
ODS-10      036267       AAA   57321
POS-11      036268       AAC   8435435   764   frd
```

desired output :

```
    ADZ-4       128720       XZA   451351351   5135   jhgt   215
    SZQ-2       036051       XSZ   55654   grt
    KFD-9       036266       XWQ 
    ODS-10      036267       XZA   57321
    POS-11      036268       XWQ   8435435   764   frd
```

I tried the following command line.

```
 awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next} {if ($3 in a){$3=a[1]}; print $0}' File1 File2
```

but I'm pretty sure I'm not doing something right in the second curly brakes, since it prints out a file with the third column removed.
If I only had a few, I would happily use sed by I have 500+ substitutions to do...

Any help would be appreciated and if you can explain so I can learn from my mistake, I would be immensely grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't reference the associative array in the right way. Please change:

```
...{if ($3 in a){$3=a[1]}; print $0...
```

into:

```
...{if ($3 in a){$3=a[$3]}; print $0
```

The keys of your array `a` are `AAA,AAB...` instead of `1,2,3...`.

Comment: Thank you !

it does work a lot better. Print $0 doesn't show the corrected file though but print $3 does output the correct column, I stored it in a file named "temp.txt" and replace the column with another one-liner. Not elegant but it works.

Comment: @AbiT. print $0 didn't work as your expectation, this is likely because you didn't set the `OFS`. but since you didn't define the "incorrect file", it is my guess. anyway, if the problem in your question is solved, please consider accepting the answer. thx